# Use same key in react 16 will cause warning, but all items still displayed

Tags: reactjs

Before 16, the same key components are just ignored. How can React 16 do that? Use an another special random key to distinguish if same?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: [{id: 0, name: 'andy'}, {id: 1, name: 'mary'}, {id: 1, name: 'halo'}]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.users.map((user) => {
          return <div key={user.id}>{user.name}</div>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I use React 16 to compile. It got the result displayed as below:

```
andy
mary
halo
```

But if I run the code in codepen (react 0.13.0), I got

```
andy
mary
```

https://codepen.io/cppalien/pen/ywvmOm/

And I think this was right, because react use key to distinguish components, the third component key is same with the second one, so it's ignored.

Comment: just checked your codepen, you didn't add `react-dom` to it, so your codepen react app does,'t render anything right now.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the index as a fallback when no key is provided. So, it only affects the end result if the elements are then reordered.

Comment: But I provided keys, just the keys are same